# Song lyrics and poetry

Tags: discussion, faq, on-topic-definition

Are song lyrics and poetry on topic or off? Poetry seems like a shoo-in, but song lyrics could be a problem if the question veers into music.

Answer (score 8):

**On-topic** if the question about song lyrics is a literary question - in other words questions about imagery, rhyming, rhythm (for the lyrics themselves), and word choice seem like they should be allowed.

**Off-topic** or at least a gray area if the question is primarily musical - matching lyrics to a tune, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Well, frankly, this is more in line with what I'd be more interested in seeing.

Posting a few lines and asking for editing or phrasing advice is more appealing to me than answering questions about word processing software.

Comment: I think everyone's afraid to do that because no one has done it yet.  The questions on the main page have been rather stagnant today :/

Comment: @StrixVaria: Yea, just a touch. Sigh. I'll try and come up with something.